# Вывод информации для юзера

Tags: python

Делаю первые шаги в изучении программирования. Начал пару недель назад. 
Задача такова: надо спросить пользователя ввести название животного и цифры. Используя цифру введённую пользователем, нужно спросить пользователя ввести столько же цветов, каждый на отдельной строке. После того, как юзер завершит ввод цветов, программа должна вывести строки с названием цветов введённые юзером.
Выглядит примерно так(ввод юзера указано жирным шрифтом):

```
Enter an animal: cat

How many colors: 4

Color 1: white

Color 2: red

Color 3: blue

Color 4: brown

white cat

red cat

blue cat

brown cat
```

Начал Я так:

```
colors = ["red", "blue", "black", "white", "yellow", "orange", "purple", "brown", "grey", "gray", "silver", "green"]

userAnimal = input("Enter an animal: ")
userNumber = input("How many colors: ")

userNumber = int(userNumber)
```

А дальше совсем не знаю как.

Comment: Нужно использовать цикл ``for``.

Answer (score 0):

```
# colors = ["red", "blue", "black", "white", "yellow", "orange", "purple", "brown", "grey", "gray", "silver", "green"]

userAnimal = input("Enter an animal: ")
userNumber = input("How many colors: ")

userNumber = int(userNumber)

userColors = []
for i in range(1, userNumber + 1):
    userColors.append(input("Color " + str(i) + ": "))

for i in range(0, userNumber):
    print(userColors[i] + " " + userAnimal)
```

Здесь нужно использовать перебор циклом. Только я не понимаю, зачем тут список colors?

Answer (score 0):

Укороченный вариант

```
a = input("animal\n")
[print(i + a) for i in ["{} ".format(input("Color {}\n".format(i + 1))) for i in range(int(input("number\n")))]]
```

Вывод:

```
animal
Cat
number
2
Color 1
Red
Color 2
Green
Red Cat
Green Cat
```

Так же можно использовать ваш список `color` и выдавать цвета рандомно

```
import random
colors = ["red", "blue", "black", "white", "yellow", "orange", "purple", "brown", "grey", "gray", "silver", "green"]
random.shuffle(colors)
a = input("animal\n")
[print("{0} {1}".format(colors[i], a)) for i in range(int(input("number person\n")))]
```

Вывод (В каждом варианте по разному):

```
animal
Cat
number person
4
yellow Cat
black Cat
grey Cat
blue Cat
```